# Undefined Variable on PHP using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Hi i am having trouble with my code . This code is working actually way back 2018 and I don't know why it is throwing errors now for example this code

**database.php**

```
<?php
session_start();


//Database connection variables
/*---------DEVELOPMENT-----------*/
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'db_name';

try
{
    $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    return "Error!: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/*******/lib/library.php';

$user = new DemoLib($db_con);
?>
```

and I am calling now the user to get the other functionality like this

**administration.php**

```
<?php
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/*********/database/database.php';


if($user->is_LoggedIn()!="")
{
    $user->Redirect('admin-index-add');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($user->Login($username,$password))
    {
        $user->Redirect('admin-index-add');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Wrong Details!";
    }
}
?>
```

But it keeps throwing me this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\wamp64\www**********\admin\administration.php on line 5

can someone please point out why this work is getting an error.

Comment: it says the error is in administrator.php but you have not posted administrator.php? if you accidentally said administration: it appears that $user is not defined, so you would have to define it somewhere before it reaches that line

Answer (score 0):

The method is_LoggedIn definitely belongs to a class. Have you already instantiated this?

```
$user = NEW UserClass();
```

Comment: it is already on the database.php . that is why i use require_once on top sir